# facebook oAuth External Authentication redirect url doesnot work in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have created a MVC SPA application with Individaul Auth enabled. And updated all the OWIN DLLs to 3.1.0 version. Updated the registered AppID and Key in the **startup.cs** (got from the DeConsole)

'Facebook' button is enabled in the login page and on clicking it takes me to the FB login page to provide my credentials. After logging in, it is NOTasking any confirmation such google ask (Application try to access your basic information Allow/Deny) then redirect back to the application. But without any basic information got from FB. Am i missing anything here
The return url is always localhost:33343/Account/Login#=_..

I thought Microsoft 
is providing everything we needed but not actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting acccess_denied from OWIN middleware. Try to put debugger in Account Controller action 'ExternalLoginCallback'.

I assume you have added http://your_domain/signin-facebook as allowed redirect_uri in facebook. Note, https is not mandatory here, facebook still provide credentials if it is http.

I also assume you have updated your nuget packages to Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.1.0.
Useful Link : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/38

Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions to see allowed permissions. Ask for proper scopes and fields as below code:

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "....",
            AppSecret = "....",

            AuthenticationType = "Facebook",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,                

            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FacebookAccessToken", ctx.AccessToken));
                    foreach (var claim in ctx.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                        string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();

                        if (!ctx.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        {
                            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
                        }
                    }                 
                }

            }
        };

        // Set requested scope
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

        // Set requested fields
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Fields.Add("email");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Fields.Add("first_name");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Fields.Add("last_name");                 

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```